# Kendo UI grid - grouped Header Columns

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

This is not related to the grouping function where you can drag things to the header and it groups the grid.

I am trying to present grid columns in categories for organization in a large grid showing complex financial data for my project. I have created a very very simplified mockup of what I am trying to accomplish in google docs at this link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11BZGrV5IE2zvh3Ya38jgCN1lgOqMFXegdwAOmv-bLZg/edit?usp=sharing

The solution would need top play nice with column resizing. We would disable the ability to re-order columns for this display so that shouldn't be an issue.

[image]

Comment: Are 'Costs' 'Forecasts Values' and 'Actual Values' related or are they separate grids?

Comment: this is the display of one grid. Imagine in excel you created a row above your column headers and "merged cells".. (exactly what i did in google docs)

Comment: Basically I have categories of columns. I need a clean way to show this in the UI

Comment: I am asking if they are related because the kendo grid binds each row as an object. If the items within the row are not related, then you have to treat each as if they are separate grids. If not, and the values within the rows are related, you are able to customize the color of the headers to create separation and bind it directly to your model.

Comment: Sorry not trying to be dense. I'm not really sure what you mean by related.    I just want an extra row above a grids headers where I can display columns under a group. When a column is resized it should also resize the header.

I didn't see any options in Kendo to accomplish this.

Comment: However I think i did mention that it should be just 1 grid. Not sure if that make it "related" as you mentioned

Comment: The field names are categorized... this has nothing to do with the data per say. I want to show the fields in categories

Comment: See my answer (posting now)

Comment: What i meant by related is this: are the rows one object? If you apply a query to get that row, will it return all values (cost, forecast, actual), or just cost? If it returns all values, you may be able to use 'fake headers' as explained in your link from telerik.

Comment: It's a no go because they can't be resized. We'll have to wait to see what this pivot grid does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding a multi-row header w/ colspan

From the official forum:

> Multirow headers will be available in the Pivot Grid, which we are currently developing with the idea of releasing it for Q2 2014. We may port the implementation for the standard Grid for subsequent releases, but I am afraid I can't provide official information about the timing and probability at this point.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/multiple-header-rows

http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/road

If anyone cares this is how we overcame the problem using slick grid. We are updating to kendo so we will just carry this forward until we have a grid that has these capabilties. We used a legend and then applied a CSS to each header

[image]

Comment: If you are still looking for an solution to the your question then please refer to **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812800/visual-grouping-with-kendo-grid?answertab=active#tab-top**

Comment: Ok thanks, issue is the same w/ that it doesn't support column resizing... at least at a glance. We ended up going w/ the colors and the legend for now and the client doesn't know any better so they are cool with it!