# Multi-column Headers With Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-grid, grouping

I don't know what this is called, and I've messed around a lot with the headerTemplate but can't figure out how to produce this look. I need the second row of column names to 'act normally' in terms of sorting and filtering, but everything I try breaks that. I have no idea if headerTemplate is even the right way to do this? Is there a name for this kind of grouping? My research is turning up a whole lot of nothing, so I suspect I'm using the wrong keywords. What is this layout called?

[image]

Note: for security reasons I can't post a code dump (super nervous about the image too). If a specific thing is needed, please let me know and I'll try to anonymize it. But, mostly I'm just looking for suggestions to try other than playing with the headerTemplate.

Comment: Rather than add an answer. The Pivot Grid feature has just been released in *Beta* within the Q2 2014 release for Kendo UI. Take a look at the samples at the telerik website to see how this works. Note this is only available to PRO customers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to achieve multirow Group headers via Kendo grid on MVC, although there were  discussion to add the feature in the current version(2014Q2) of Kendo. See below link for more reference:
  [Pivot Grid StackOverflow Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23503513/kendo-ui-grid-grouped-header-columns?answertab=active#tab-top)

However, you can achieve the multirow header option via jquery on databound event of the grid. But it is a workaround rather than a perfect soultion.
Please see the js function for databound event to add multirow header:

```
 function onDataBound(arg) {
     var myElem = document.getElementById('trParentHeader'); //Check if Parent Header Group exist
     if (myElem == null){ // if parent Header doesnot exist then add the Parent Header
        $("#grid").find("th.k-header").parent().before("<tr id='trParentHeader'>  <th colspan='2' class='k-header'><strong>Products + Unit Price</strong></th>  <th scope='col' class='k-header'><strong>Single Units in Stock</strong></th></tr>");
     }
  }
```

For more understanding and a working example please see below Sample:

[MultiRow-Column Header Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/GH35Z/)

Please let me know if you if you have any queries.

Comment: Clever, I like it :)  Thanks very much! "Multi-column header" I'll remember that now!

Comment: This was the best solution for myself. My issue was that my grid is dynamically generated and the navtively supported kendo code was not working for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is now natively supported by the Kendo grid. Here's an [example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/multicolumnheaders).